# String subscript out of range Visual c++

Tags: string, visual-c++, runtime-error

I am working in this program to pull certain information out of an exported registry file. I am new to using Visual Studio and this compiles and runs fine in 2012 but I did that before I realized that I needed 2010 to run the application on Windows XP. When I run the code in 2010 it gives me a runtime error saying "string subscript out of range". Any direction with this bug would be greatly appreciated.

```
    // SoftwareList.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
    //

    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    class Node
    {
    public:
        string name;
        string publisher;
        string version;
        string installDate;
        int position;
    };

    void quickSort(Node arr[], int left, int right)
    {
        int i = left, j = right;
        Node temp;
        Node pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];

        /* partition */
        while (i <= j) {
            while (arr[i].name < pivot.name)
                i++;
            while (arr[j].name > pivot.name)
                j--;
            if (i <= j) {
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }
        /* recursion */
        if (left < j)
            quickSort(arr, left, j);
        if (i < right)
            quickSort(arr, i, right);
    }

    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        string line;
        string field;
        string filter;
        int index = 0;
        int arraySize = 10000;
        Node *programs;
            programs = new Node[arraySize];

        //Export the needed registry keys
        printf("Exporting Registry List\n");
        system("reg export        HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall         reg_out_unicode.txt");
system("cmd /a /c type reg_out_unicode.txt>reg_out_ansi.txt");
system("del reg_out_unicode.txt");

//Clean up the registry keys to only show the info needed
ifstream infile;
ofstream outfile;
infile.open("reg_out_ansi.txt");
outfile.open("SoftwareList.txt");
Node currentProgram;

//Initialize the new Node
currentProgram.name = "";
currentProgram.publisher = "";
currentProgram.version = "";

while (getline(infile,line))
{

    if (line[0] == '[' )
    {
        //Add the last filled node
        if (!currentProgram.name.empty())
        {
            currentProgram.position = index;
            programs[index] = currentProgram;
            index++;
        }

        //Initialize the empty Node
        currentProgram.name = "";
        currentProgram.publisher = "";
        currentProgram.version = "";
    }
    //Find the first " and pull the string from after that
    //const char *temp = line.c_str();
    char *temp = new char[line.size() + 1];
    strcpy(temp,line.c_str());

    if (*temp == '"')
    {
        *temp++;
        while (*temp != '"') //Stops at the next "
        {
            field.push_back(*temp++); //Add what is in between the "" into the field string for checking
        }
    }

    if (strcmp(field.c_str(),"DisplayName") == 0) // Grab the DisplayName of a program
    {
        field.push_back(*temp++);
        field.push_back(*temp++);
        field.clear();
        while (1)
        {
            if (*temp == '"')
            {
                *temp++;
                while (*temp != '"') //Stops at the next "
                {
                    field.push_back(*temp); //Add what is in between the "" into the field string for checking
                    *temp++;                        
                }
                break;
            } else {
                *temp++;
            }
        }
        currentProgram.name = field;
    }

    if (strcmp(field.c_str(),"DisplayVersion") == 0) // Grab the DisplayVersion of a program
    {
        field.push_back(*temp++);
        field.push_back(*temp++);
        field.clear();
        while (1)
        {
            if (*temp == '"')
            {
                *temp++;
                while (*temp != '"') //Stops at the next "
                {
                    field.push_back(*temp); //Add what is in between the "" into the field string for checking
                    *temp++;

                }
                break;
            } else {
                *temp++;
            }
        }
        currentProgram.version = field;
    }

    if (strcmp(field.c_str(),"Publisher") == 0) // Grab the Publisher of a program
    {
        field.push_back(*temp++);
        field.push_back(*temp++);
        field.clear();
        while (1)
        {
            if (*temp == '"')
            {
                *temp++;
                while (*temp != '"') //Stops at the next "
                {
                    field.push_back(*temp); //Add what is in between the "" into the field string for checking
                    *temp++;                        
                }
                break;
            } else {
                *temp++;
            }
        }
        currentProgram.publisher = field;
    }

    if (strcmp(field.c_str(),"InstallDate") == 0) // Grab the Publisher of a program
    {
        field.push_back(*temp++);
        field.push_back(*temp++);
        field.clear();
        while (1)
        {
            if (*temp == '"')
            {
                *temp++;
                while (*temp != '"') //Stops at the next "
                {
                    field.push_back(*temp); //Add what is in between the "" into the field string for checking
                    *temp++;                        
                }
                break;
            } else {
                *temp++;
            }
        }
        currentProgram.installDate = field;
    }

    field.clear();
}

cout << "Registry Successfully Parsed" << endl;

//Sort the output
quickSort(programs,0,arraySize - 1);
cout << "Sorting Successful" << endl;

cout << '\n' << "Choose Output Filtering Method" << endl;
cout << "-------------------------" << endl;
cout << "  " << "[1] All Software" << endl;
cout << "  " << "[2] All But Microsoft" << endl;
cout << "  " << "[3] Filter By Software Title" << endl;
cout << "  " << "[4] Filter By Software Publisher" << endl;
cout << "  " << "[5] Filter By Install Date" << endl;
cout << "Enter Choice: ";

//Write File Header
outfile << "Title" << '\t' << "Version" << '\t' << "Publisher" << '\t' << "Install Date" << endl;

while (1)
{
    cin >> filter;
    if (!strcmp(filter.c_str(),"1"))
    {
        //Print all elements to outfile
        cout << "Writing Output File" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(programs[i].name.c_str(),"") != 0)
            {
                outfile << programs[i].name.c_str() << '\t' << programs[i].version.c_str() << '\t' << programs[i].publisher.c_str() << '\t' << programs[i].installDate.c_str() << endl;
            }
        }
        break;
    } else  if (!strcmp(filter.c_str(),"2")) {
        //Print selected elements to outfile
        cout << "Writing Output File" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(programs[i].name.c_str(),"") != 0)
            {
                if (programs[i].publisher.find("Microsoft") == string::npos)
                {
                    if (programs[i].name.find("Microsoft") == string::npos)
                    {
                        outfile << programs[i].name.c_str() << '\t' << programs[i].version.c_str() << '\t' << programs[i].publisher.c_str() << '\t' << programs[i].installDate.c_str() << endl;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    }else if (!strcmp(filter.c_str(),"3")) {
        string title;
        cout << '\n' << "Enter Title (Case Sensitive): ";
        cin >> title;
        cout << endl;

        //Print selected elements to outfile
        cout << "Writing Output File" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(programs[i].name.c_str(),"") != 0)
            {
                if (programs[i].name.find(title) != string::npos)
                {
                    outfile << programs[i].name.c_str() << '\t' << programs[i].version.c_str() << '\t' << programs[i].publisher.c_str() << '\t' << programs[i].installDate.c_str() << endl;
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    } else  if (!strcmp(filter.c_str(),"4")) {

        string publisher;
        cout << '\n' << "Enter Publisher (Case Sensitive): ";
        cin >> publisher;
        cout << endl;

        //Print selected elements to outfile
        cout << "Writing Output File" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(programs[i].name.c_str(),"") != 0)
            {
                if (programs[i].publisher.find(publisher) != string::npos)
                {
                    outfile << programs[i].name.c_str() << '\t' << programs[i].version.c_str() << '\t' << programs[i].publisher.c_str() << '\t' << programs[i].installDate.c_str() << endl;
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    } else if (!strcmp(filter.c_str(),"5")) {

        string date;
        cout << '\n' << "Enter Date (YYYYMMDD): ";
        cin >> date;
        cout << endl;

        //Print selected elements to outfile
        cout << "Writing Output File" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(programs[i].name.c_str(),"") != 0)
            {
                if (programs[i].installDate.find(date) != string::npos)
                {
                    outfile << programs[i].name.c_str() << '\t' << programs[i].version.c_str() << '\t' << programs[i].publisher.c_str() << '\t' << programs[i].installDate.c_str() << endl;
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    } else {
        cout << "Invalid Input... Try Again" << endl;
    }
}

//Close and clean up files
infile.close();
outfile.close();
system("del reg_out_ansi.txt");
return 0;
    }
```

Comment: at least try narrowing down the problem.

Comment: From looking at it I believe the problem is in lines 95-97.
//const char *temp = line.c_str();
char *temp = new char[line.size() + 1];
strcpy(temp,line.c_str());
The commented line is meant to do the same thing as the following two lines but neither of them works.

Comment: try using the debugger

Comment: Ran it through the debugger with breakpoints on every line. I also changed it to just a for loop to copy the characters one by one. All situations result in the same error. Is there some other option with the debugger that will give me more info that I can try?